# How can I use php file from vue-cli?

Tags: php, api, vue.js, axios

I have a problem when I make a handling to data.php in my vue-cli project directory:

```
axios.get('@/data.php')
.then(resp =>
(console.log(resp))
```

I receive a 404 error. I would like to have API code on data.php and use this data in vue-cli. How can I do this?

Comment: I am dealing with the same issue. My guess is because Vue runs with Node, but PHP needs Apache. But I am also running Apache with Xampp, so it's wierd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/using-php-with-vue-cli/52842/3

Basically you need to connect your frontend and backend servers in vue.config.js.